# Telnet session - can't run commands

Tags: centos, telnet, command-line-interface

I have 2 VMs running CentOS 5.0 and I configured telnet on both of them.

I can telnet from one to another... but when I type **ls** or **cd** at the prompt I get a message like this

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got nothing in your path. Try `/bin/ls` and see if that works. If it is, you'll have to add common directories to your $PATH, or execute your .bashrc file.

Also, you really shouldn't be using telnet, as it's hugely insecure. You'd be *much* better of installing SSH (or enabling it, it's often installed by default).

Comment: I've tried which ls and got the /bin/ls but still I get no expected output.

Comment: @Joao: Does `echo *` give you a list of files? It's curious that `which` works, but `ls` and `cd` don't (especially since `cd` is a builtin). Do `pwd` and `/bin/pwd` work?